# How to set LLVM &AnalysisType::ID For Analysis Pass

Tags: clang, llvm, static-analysis, llvm-clang

I'm trying to create an analysis pass. My code is shown below. I'm using Adrian Sampson approach for building the .so file (https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asampson/blog/llvm.html).

```
          #include "llvm/Pass.h"
      #include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
      #include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
      #include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"
      #include "llvm/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.h"
      #include "DataDependence.h"
      #include "ControlDependence.h"
      #include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
      #include "llvm/Analysis/AliasAnalysis.h"
      #include "llvm/Support/ErrorHandling.h"
      #include "llvm/Analysis/PostDominators.h"
      #include "llvm/Analysis/MemoryDependenceAnalysis.h"
      #include "llvm/Analysis/LoopInfo.h"
      using namespace llvm;
      namespace {
        struct SkeletonPass : public ModulePass {
          static char ID;
        SkeletonPass() : ModulePass(ID) {}
        virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const  {
            AU.addRequired<LoopInfoWrapperPass>();
            AU.addRequired<DominatorTreeWrapperPass>();
            //  AU.addPreserved<AliasAnalysis>();
            // AU.setPreservesCFG();
          // AU.addRequired<PostDominatorTree>();

        }
        virtual   bool runOnModule(Module &M);
          };
           bool SkeletonPass::runOnModule(Module &M) {
             for (auto mi = M.begin(); mi != M.end(); ++mi) {
               if (mi->isDeclaration())
                 continue;
                //  MemoryDependenceAnalysis &MDA = getAnalysis<MemoryDependenceAnalysis>(*mi);
                 PostDominatorTree &PDT = getAnalysis<PostDominatorTree>(*mi); //Error is Here
             }
         errs() << "Test:\n";
         }
      }
      char SkeletonPass::ID = 0;
      static RegisterPass<SkeletonPass> X("SkeletonPass", "Hello World Pass",
                                   false /* Only looks at CFG */,
                                   true /* Analysis Pass */);
```

The error I'm getting is below

```
        In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/Pass.h:388:0,
                     from /media/quentinmayo/storage/Research/LLVM Dev/llvm-pass-skeleton/skeleton/Skeleton.cpp:1:
    /usr/local/include/llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h: In instantiation of ‘AnalysisType& llvm::Pass::getAnalysis(llvm::Function&) [with AnalysisType = llvm::PostDominatorTree]’:
    /media/quentinmayo/storage/Research/LLVM Dev/llvm-pass-skeleton/skeleton/Skeleton.cpp:34:71:   required from here
    /usr/local/include/llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h:253:38: error: ‘ID’ is not a member of ‘llvm::PostDominatorTree’
       return getAnalysisID<AnalysisType>(&AnalysisType::ID, F);
                                          ^
    skeleton/CMakeFiles/SkeletonPass.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'skeleton/CMakeFiles/SkeletonPass.dir/Skeleton.cpp.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [skeleton/CMakeFiles/SkeletonPass.dir/Skeleton.cpp.o] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: recipe for target 'skeleton/CMakeFiles/SkeletonPass.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [skeleton/CMakeFiles/SkeletonPass.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The error is saying I'm missing AnalysisType::ID. I would like to pass the AliasAnalysis pointer to another class for analysis.   I'm confused what this AnalysisType::ID would be? Additionally, can someone explain the relationship between getAnalysisUsage and getAnalysis when creating pass for analysis? Understanding compiler theory doesn't really help me with working with LLVM.

http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Pass.html#ab78af013d3a11515403da8517f8f3d4a

Answer (score 2):

I needed to call the class member getDomTree .

DominatorTree &DI = getAnalysis(*mi).getDomTree();

Advice for others: get friendly with the doxygen pages and reading header files. And if it comes to it, look into the source of your current LLVM build.

Also,AliasAnalysis is now AAResultsWrapperPass.